# How can I segue from view controller to Split view Controller Without making it my root View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

Navigating from my root view Controller i.e a `UIViewController` seems no problem at all. But when I segue from other view Controllers to the Split View,

> Split View Controllers cannot be pushed to a Navigation Controller

happens.

Here is my appdelegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication,  didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    let split = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("SplitViewContoller") as! UISplitViewController
    let splitViewController = split
    let navigationController = splitViewController.viewControllers[splitViewController.viewControllers.count-1] as! UINavigationController
    navigationController.topViewController!.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = splitViewController.displayModeButtonItem()
    splitViewController.delegate = self
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't.

[Split View Controllers from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/SplitViewControllers.html).

> A split view controller must always be the root of any interface you
>   create. In other words, you must always install the view from a
>   UISplitViewController object as the root view of your application’s
>   window.